# CSS Scaling Specified Pixels to Dynamic

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web-frontend

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #FF5722;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

How fit **inner div with specific pixels** to the screen height or width **with CSS** *keeping ratio the same*?

Comment: Just need scaling without changing width and height pixels of inner.

Comment: why ? and why not simply use 100% in width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  background-color: #FF5722;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not calc(), something like scale(100vh)